# Colourful circles that run tests not appearing on Visual Studio Coded UI Test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I have created a Coded UI Test for a web application on Visual Studio. Things don't seem to be quite right, and while my code is perfect, and includes test methods wrapped in a test class under a namespace, the small colourful circles that appear next to each test method are missing.

However, in another part of the solution, on another Coded UI Test, the circles appear and everything works perfectly. I have set the web application as the start up project, but nothing is really restoring the circles.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you show perhaps a screen shot of what you mean or something of the like? It is not quite clear what you are asking.

Comment: I'm on a computer that doesn't have visual studio on it, but most test cases have small circles in the far left column, that when you click them, run the particular test you are on. Except mine are missing.

Comment: Are the tests running?

Comment: Yes, and I can run them in test explorer, its just the circles that are missing.

Comment: _"the small colourful circles that appear next to each test method are missing"_ - weren't those removed after VS2010?

Comment: How do you know they are running?

Comment: User2830378 - they exist in visual studio 2013, they run on a coded ui test I have been given, but when I set up my own coded UI test on the same project, they can't be found?

Comment: They appear in the Test Explorer and have failed written next to each of them.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install Resharper: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html

Could be that your test solution (which shows the circles) opens in an older version of Visual Studio, where Resharper is installed.

And your test solution opens in another version of Visual Studio, where Resharper is not installed.

Comment: Thanks, but it opens in Visual Studio 2013. I have resharper installed (but I think you are right in that it has something to do with resharper)

Comment: Maybe re-installing Resharper will help?